# How to use jquery to get classes starting with a value and adding events to checkboxes in each of the classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a set of classes all beginning with `marg-`. Something like the pattern below:

```
'<div class="marg-1 row-">'+
                '<p class="subject-math col-6">Mathematics</p>'+
                '<div class="check-div col-1" > <input type="checkbox" class="math-check"  /></div>'+
           '</div>'+
           '<div class="marg-2 row-">'+
                '<p class="subject-eng col-6">English</p>'+
                '<div class="check-div col-1" > <input type="checkbox" class="eng-check"  /></div>'+
           '</div>'+
           '<div class="marg-3 row-">'+
                '<p class="subject-phy col-6">Physics</p>'+
                '<div class="check-div col-1" > <input type="checkbox" class="phy-check"  /></div>'+
           '</div>'
```

I want to write jquery code that will locate them all and add an onselect event to the checkboxes in them.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at Jquery selectors doc.

```
$('div[class^="marg-"]').find('checkbox').bind('change', function() {
    // Your code here...   
    alert($( this ).val());
});
```

Comment: It does not seem to be working. The elements are dynamically generated and I add a function encapsulating the above solution to the containing div's onload. But I get no alert.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, I just discovered that in my use case, the class names were defined in the reverse order. Thanks a lot!